# Accessing (attributes of) a list of variables from a data frame based on a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, attr

I have a (big) data frame with variables which each have a `comment` attribute.

```
# Basic sample data
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 5:1, c = 5:9, d = 9:5, e = 1:5)
comment(df$a) <- "Some explanation"
comment(df$b) <- "Some description"
comment(df$c) <- "etc."
```

I would like to extract the `comment` attributes for *some* of those variables, as well as a lit of possible values.

So I start by defining the list of variables I want to extract:

```
variables_to_extract = c("a", "b", "e")
```

I would normally work on a subset of the data frame, but then I cannot access the attributes (e.g., `comment`) nor the list of possible values of *each variable*.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% select(one_of(variables_to_export)) %>% comment()
# accesses only the 'comment' attribute of the whole data frame (df), hence NULL
```

I also tried to access through `df[[variables_to_export]]`, but it generates an error...

```
df[[variables_to_export]]
# Error: Recursive Indexing failed at level 2
```

I wanted to extract everything into a data frame, but because of the recursive indexing error, it doesn't work.

```
meta <- data.frame(variable = variables_to_export,
                   description = comment(papers[[variables_to_export]]),
                   values = papers[[vairables_to_export]] %>% 
                     unique() %>% na.omit() %>% sort() %>% paste(collapse = ", "))
# Error: Recursive Indexing failed at level 2
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% select(one_of(variables_to_extract)) %>% map(comment)` or in base, `lapply(df[, variables_to_extract], comment)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a data.frame is a list, you can use `lapply` or `purrr::map` to apply a function (e.g. `comment`) to each vector it contains:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% select(one_of(variables_to_extract)) %>% map(comment)    # in base R, lapply(df[variables_to_extract], comment)
#> $a
#> [1] "Some explanation"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "Some description"
#> 
#> $e
#> NULL
```

To put it in a data.frame,

```r
data_frame(variable = variables_to_extract, 
           # iterate over variable, subset df and if NULL replace with NA; collapse to chr
           description = map_chr(variable, ~comment(df[[.x]]) %||% NA), 
           values = map(variable, ~df[[.x]] %>% unique() %>% sort()))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   variable      description    values
#>      <chr>            <chr>    <list>
#> 1        a Some explanation <int [5]>
#> 2        b Some description <int [5]>
#> 3        e             <NA> <int [5]>
```

This leaves `values` as a list column, which is usually more useful, but if you'd rather, add in `toString` to collapse it and use `map_chr` to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

we can use `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(comment, df[variables_to_extract])
#$a
#[1] "Some explanation"

#$b
#[1] "Some description"

#$e
#NULL
```